# occassionally my screen goes to a series of historical windows (previous apps, searches, etc) how does that come up?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

1. Ready to select an app
2. the screen changes to show a series of windows (chronological in order) of the last usages of the phone
3. How do I access that?  Where is the command or what is the finger-to-screen command?

Answer (score 2):

This "Menu" comes up when you either long-press the Home button or the Multitask button,
which is usually located to the right of the Home key.

If you are using a Samsung device, this button is usually located to the left of the Home key.